# What is the answer to this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know the answer to this infinite sum due to it being "slightly unusual". We "apply" the Thue-Morse sequence (e.g.: $ABBABAAB\ BAABABBA\ BAABABBA\ ABBABAAB$) to the signs of the terms in the infinite(ly long) sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$, and when written out the sum becomes:
$$+\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{64}-\frac{1}{128}...$$
I thought of separating it out into $+$'s and $-$'s but that didn't seem to get me anywhere and I can't see any patterns in the partial sums.
(Note that I am not very good with infinite sums.)
What I'm asking for is the answer to this sum along with how the answer is achieved and whether it relates to the numbers $e$ and $\pi$ (by "relates to" I mean whether there is anything you can do to $e$ and $\pi$ in order to turn them into the answer to this infinite sum, I'm not sure what the term for this is though). I am reasonably sure that this series converges because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2^n}=-2$ which implies that it would be between +2 and −2, but I do not know if this is valid reasoning.

Comment: You are sure the series is convergent and does not diverge?

Comment: @tatan I am reasonably sure because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2^n}=-2$ which implies that it would be between $+2$ and $-2$.

Comment: The sequence is known as the Thue-Morse sequence.

Comment: @CatalinZara Thanks, I'll put it in the answer.

Comment: This is the Thue-Morse sequence ([A010060 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A010060)). For programmers, it is the bit parity of the non-negative integers: $s_n = A$ if $n$ has an even number of $1$'s in its binary expansion.

Comment: @TonyK: It was not the Thue-Morse sequence when I wrote the comment. I looked for a plausible continuation. But now that it is the Thue-Morse sequence, I will delete the comment.

Comment: @tatan: The series is absolutely convergent, hence convergent. :)

Comment: The series converges and is equal to 2-4P=0.35018..., where P is the [Thue-Morse constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseConstant.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an almost similar constant, the [Prouhet-Thue-Morse constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Thue%E2%80%93Morse_constant), which consists in the real number whose binary expansion is the Thue-Morse sequence and has been proven to be transcendental:
$$\tau = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{t_i}{2^{i+1}}$$ where $t_i$ is the $i$-th term of the Thue-Morse sequence: $(t_0, t_1, t_2, t_3, \dots) = (0, 1, 1, 0, \dots)$.

In your case, you are considering $$S = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{t_i}}{2^{i}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - 2t_i}{2^{i}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}} - 4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{t_i}{2^{i+1}}$$

Therefore, $S = 2 - 4\tau = 0.35018386544\dots$, which is a transcendental number (since $\tau$ is).

Comment: After a bit of staring at how you "transformed" (for lack of a better term) $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{t_i}}{2^{i}}$ into $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}} - 4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{t_i}{2^{i+1}}$, I understood it :D